# Why can't you call outerHTML on $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

When you want to get the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) of an entire DOM element (wrapper included), you can do the following (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749)):

```
$('#myElementId')[0].outerHTML
```

But what you *can't* do is call `outerHTML` on `$(this)` inside e.g. a click listener or selector function body scope:

```
$(this).outerHTML //Doesn't complete in IntelliSense, returns undefined in browser
```

or

```
$(this)[0].outerHTML //Correction, this DOES work, but it doesn't complete in IntelliSense
```

because IntelliSense won't show `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` in those circumstances, although with *vanilla JavaScript* you can do:

```
document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).outerHTML
```

So... what's up with that?

Comment: Did you actually try in the browser itself? I don't particularly see the point of using `outerHTML` that way but that should work.

Comment: Maybe Intellisense is unable to determine that `$(this)[0]` is a DOM element, so it doesn't suggest DOM members.

Comment: Leaning towards @FrédéricHamidi's explanation. Do you get any intellisense on `$(this).get(0).outerHTML`?

Comment: @JordanGray no, I don't

Comment: Huh, interesting, I thought that would work! Are you getting autocomplete hints for the `.get` method, even? (I've tried to reproduce this, but am getting different results from you.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`outerHTML` is a DOM property; jQuery doesn't expose all DOM properties.

If you have a jQuery object, you can only directly access those properties and methods that jQuery exposes, and vice versa for DOM objects.

In object-oriented terms, jQuery objects don't inherit from DOM objects, they contain them.

Saying `$x[0]` gets you the DOM object for the first element represented by a jQuery object.

Comment: Questioner does say that Intellisense fails to complete `$(this)[0].outerHTML`, so it's not only a jQuery object / DOM element issue.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I guess Intellisense isn't clever enough to determine that a jQuery object's array accessor `[]` returns a DOM element.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it actually does *not* complete `$(this)[0].outerHTML` although it works in the browser.

Comment: @Wim, yup, that's what I said :) Several of us are thinking this is an Intellisense limitation. In any case, both `this.outerHTML` and `$(this)[0].outerHTML` will work as expected, even if Intellisense apparently cannot infer that.

Comment: thank you for your insights and prompt answers, people!

Comment: The intellisense issue very much depends on what intellisense your using, I find the built in intellisense in VisualStudio terrible at js for example. Trusting intellisense in none compiled languages like js is always going to be hit and miss.

Answer (score 20):

You can use directly `this` to access `outerHTML` of the current object instead of indirectly going through `$(this)` as this represents the DOM object (which has `outerHTML` property) whereas `$(this)` represents jQuery object.

```
this.outerHTML
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery selector returns an array-like jQuery object which has no outerHTML property.

However, the jQuery resulting array contains DOM elements.
It means that you can actually access it this way.

```
$(".someClass")[0].outerHTML // it works for me
```

**Update:**
It works for me in every browser.
I can access array-like jQuery object in a click event handler as well.

```
$(".someClass").click(function()
{
    alert($(this)[0].outerHTML); // it works me too
});
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13btf60p/

**Update 2:**

OK, now I get your question. It should have worked.
Do you really need an IntelliSense to complete such a plain and simple construction?

Comment: The OP claims that `$(this)[0].outerHTML` doesn't work properly either. The fact that jQuery returns an array-like object is irrelevant.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It properly works for me in different browsers. I can access `$(this)[0].outerHTML` on click event.

Comment: it's uncanny how much you can come to depend on intellisense, to the point where you'll doubt anything (even the obvious) when it fails to deliver. I've wasted a LOT of time in my life feeling convinced that something SHOULD work although intellisense won't offer me options, just to discover that VS needed a restart or even an intellisense cache clear before it would properly work again. At times it can rattle your confidence, I feel.

Answer (score 1):

I will add what I found to be the correct solution to what ended up being a simple flaw in the default Visual Studio settings for future reference.

Since I didn't want to let this go, I searched further and found out that, by default, jQuery IntelliSense is somewhat deplorable out of the box in Visual Studio 2013.

Under

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript > IntelliSense > References

I set

> Reference Group: "Implicit (Web)"

and added an existing jQuery file. This solved all issues of my question and IntelliSense now suggests all members and methods correctly, although this should have simply worked out of the box instead of costing everyone a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0):

`this.outerHTML` is enough.

If you use `getElementById` maybe you can use:

```
var table = document.getElementById('blablabla');
```